# How to Print HTTP StatusCode in Go with Visual Studio Code for a Flutter Backend?

Tags: go, visual-studio-code, http-status-codes

I'm following a tutorial on integrating a Go backend with Flutter from [this YouTube video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=-Sol_RMG_fo&ab_channel=dbestech). Despite following the instructions closely, I'm unable to retrieve data from the backend into my Flutter application. The tutorial's author suggested printing the HTTP status code using `response.statusCode` to debug, but I'm unsure how to implement this in Go.

**Context:**

I'm relatively new to Go and working on a project that involves setting up a backend service for a Flutter app. The goal is to send and receive data between the Flutter frontend and the Go backend. While testing, I encountered issues with data retrieval and was advised to check the HTTP status code to diagnose the problem.

**Code:**

```
package main

import (
    "encoding/json"
    "fmt"
    "log"
    "net/http"

    "github.com/gorilla/mux"
)

type Tasks struct {
    ID         string `json:"id"`
    TaskName   string `json:"task_name"`
    TaskDetail string `json:"detail"`
    Date       string `json:"date"`
}

var tasks []Tasks

func allTasks() {
    // Code for initializing tasks omitted for brevity
}

func homePage(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
    fmt.Println("I am home page")
}

func getTasks(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
    w.Header().Set("Content-Type", "application/json")
    json.NewEncoder(w).Encode(tasks)
}

// Other handlers omitted for brevity

func handleRoutes() {
    router := mux.NewRouter()
    // Routes setup omitted for brevity
    log.Fatal(http.ListenAndServe(":3306", router))
}

func main() {
    allTasks()
    handleRoutes()
}
```

**What I've Tried:**

- I verified that the routes are correctly set up and that the server is running without errors.
- I attempted to log the output in the Flutter app to check if the data is received but found no useful information.

**Question:**

How can I modify my Go code to print the HTTP status code when making requests? I believe understanding how to log these status codes correctly will help me debug the connectivity issue with my Flutter front end.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think he said you to print the `statuscode` from flutter side. Then based on that `statuscode` you can understand where was the issue.

I have tested your code in local using postman and I am getting data.
[image: Tested with postman]

Comment: Thank you, it shows in Flutter:                                                                                                                                                                                                                                    I/chatty  (14409): uid=10128(com.example.flutter_golang_yt) 1.ui identical 1 line

I/flutter (14409): null                                                                                                                                                           
           What should I do in that case?

Comment: To be honest I am not flutter developer but if you can provide the flutter code where this error is triggered let us try to find the solution

Comment: Hello rqb I post the code below

Answer (score 0):

Hello @rqb here's the code from flutter

data_controller.dart:

```
import 'package:flutter_golang_yt/services/service.dart';
import 'package:get/get.dart';

class DataController extends GetxController{
  DataService service = DataService();
  bool _isLoading = false;
  bool get isLoading=> _isLoading;
  List<dynamic> _myData=[];
  List<dynamic> get myData=>_myData;
  Future<void> getData() async {
    _isLoading = true;
    Response response = await service.getData();
    if(response.statusCode==200){
      _myData=response.body;
      print("we got the data");
      update();
    }else{
      print(response.statusCode.toString());
    }
  }

  Future<void> postData(String task, String taskDetail) async {
    _isLoading = true;
    Response response = await service.postData({
      "task_name":task,
      "task_detail": taskDetail
    });
    if(response.statusCode==200){

      update();
      print("data post successfully");
    }else{
      print("data post failed");
    }
  }

}
```

And services.dart:

```
import 'package:get/get.dart';

class DataService extends GetConnect implements GetxService{

  Future<Response> getData()async{
    Response response=await get(
      "http://localhost:3306/gettasks",
      headers: {
        'Content-Type':'application/json; charset=UTF-8'
      }
    );

    return response;
  }

  Future<Response> postData(dynamic body)async{
    Response response=await post(
        "http://localhost:3306/create",
        body,
        headers: {
          'Content-Type':'application/json; charset=UTF-8'
        }
    );
    return response;
  }
}
```

It shows on terminal:

```
[GETX] Instance "DataController" has been created
[GETX] Instance "DataController" has been initialized
[GETX] Instance "GetMaterialController" has been created
[GETX] Instance "GetMaterialController" has been initialized
I/flutter (15548): null
```